# Passing a stream or a String to Flyway API instead of locations

Tags: flyway

I was wondering if there is a way for Flyway to accept an actual SQL migration as a string or a stream instead of searching for it on a classpath?
I'm constructing the SQL migration in Java on the fly and would like to call Flyway API and pass the migration as a paramter. 
Please, let me know if this is possible.
Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Not entirely what you are asking for, but looks like [*Java-based migrations*](http://flywaydb.org/documentation/migration/java.html) might be a solution.

Basically instead of `V1_0__script.sql` you write `V1_0__script.java` class implementing [`JdbcMigration`](http://flywaydb.org/documentation/javadoc/com/googlecode/flyway/core/api/migration/jdbc/JdbcMigration.html). Inside that class you have access to JDBC `Connection`:

```
class V1_0__script implements JdbcMigration {
  public void migrate(Connection connection) throws Exception {
    //...
  }
}
```

In `migrate()` you are free to run your custom SQL queries.

Answer (score 0):

There is **no API available** for this.

However, if you construct your SQL on the fly, it surely must be possible to construct it **one statement at a time**. Each statement can then be executed using the `Connection` parameter you get in a `JdbcMigration`

Comment: Axel, thank you.  Let me just make sure I understand what you are saying.  Since there is no way to pass the statements to the JdbcMigration, i can actually construct them within the JdbcMigration class and then just execute one class with all the statements using the API.  I guess that should work...  Do I understand your suggestion right?